# How to read data from localstorage angularjs inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, local-storage, angular-local-storage, ng-storage

There is a problem with angularjs when we hit F5 or refresh page, scope will be empty.

My scenario is:

1. Show List of Project
2. Click on one specific Project
3. Show Reports belong to this specific project

I have two cotrollers and services for showing list of projects and showing list of reports
when I click on project and show me list of report at this moment when I reresh page there is no project at all

I used localstorage with angularjs to prevent this problem.
by the help of:
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

but I am using "ng-repeat"

I inistalled "ngStorage" successffully.

I also added "ngStorage" inside my Cotroller annd appconfig angularjs

I wrote:

Writing or setting:
$localStorage.ProjectList = data;

Reading or getting from ng-repeat:
 ng-repeat="item in ProjectList" ??

I think my reading localstorage is not correct.

Thank you in advanced for any helps.

Comment: can you provide the code? it's hard to see the issues from words

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below. Just create an `array` and `push` the values into that. Then you can access that array values as you wish through a loop.

```
var a = [];
a.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yourKey')));
```